# Is the intersection of two vector subspaces $U$ and $V$ always equal to $U$ if the dimension of $U \cap V$ is equal to $\dim(U)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is the intersection of two vector subspaces $U$ and $V$ always equal to $U$ if the dimension of $U \cap V$  is equal to $\dim(U)$.

For the cases I have done until now it was. Can we generalise this ?

Comment: Why, yes, because $U\cap V$ is a subspace of $U$, and if it is a *proper* subspace, its dimension is less than that of $U$.

Comment: (Unless infinite-dimensional vector spaces are being considered).

Comment: @MikeF So an infinite dimensional vector space would be something, whose dimension we cannot define as $R^n, n\in \text{natural}$ ?

Comment: @Bernard So let's say even if we have for example: $\dim(U) = 2, \dim(V) = 2, \dim(U\cap V) = 2 \implies U\cap V=U = V \implies \text{Basis of U} = \text{Basis of V}$ $= \text{Basis of} .\ U\cap V$.

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, if $\dim(U) = \dim(U \cap V)$ is finite then the answer is "yes" because the inclusion map $U \cap V \to U$ is an injective map between vector spaces of the same finite dimension and is therefore also surjective.

However, if $\dim(U) = \dim(U \cap V)$ is not finite, then it does not follow that $U = U \cap V$. For example take $U = k^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ and $V$ to be the following subspace of $U$:
\begin{equation*}
V = \{ (0 , a_2 , a_3, \ldots ) \in U \}
\end{equation*}
Then $U \cap V = V \neq U$, and yet $\dim(U)$ and $\dim(V)$ are both equal $|\mathbb{N}|$. Indeed $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic, it's just that the inclusion map $V \to U$ is not surjective.

The same phenomenon happens with finite sets and infinite sets if you replace "dimension" with "cardinality".